# Automatize indentation in a pretty printer

Tags: ocaml, indentation, pretty-print

I have implemented a pretty printer which works quite well on a complex syntax tree. As the syntax is complicated, sometimes given a `statement` or an `expression`, it helps to print the constructors to understand their structure. To this end, I added a parameter `constructor_print`. When this variable is false, a `statement` or an `expression` is normally printed; otherwise, all the related constructors are printed in a good order. Here is a very small part of code (there are actually lots of functions `pp_...`):

```
let tercs s0 s1 =
  if !constructor_print then
    format_of_string s0
  else
    format_of_string s1  

let pp_e (chan: out_channel) (e: expression) =
  match e with
  | ADD_E_E (e0, e1) -> 
    Printf.fprintf chan  (tercs "ADD_E_E (\n%a,\n%a)" "%a + %a") pp_e e0 pp_e e1
  | UMINUS_E e ->
    Printf.fprintf chan  (tercs "UMINUS_E %a" "- %a") pp_e e
  | PARENTHESIZED_E e ->
    Printf.fprintf chan  (tercs "PARENTHESIZED_E %a" "(%a)") pp_e e
  ...

let pp_s (chan: out_channel) (s: statement) =
  ...

...
```

For instance, `3 + (-2)` is parsed to an expression `e`. When `!constructor_print` is false. `pp_e stdout e` returns `3 + (-2)`; otherwise `pp_e stdout e` returns

```
ADD_E_E (
Int 3,
PARENTHESIZED_E UMINUS_E INT 2)
```

However, the problem is, I would like to print indentation when necessary to make it more readable. For instance, I would hope the previous output could be:

```
ADD_E_E (
  INT 3,
  PARENTHESIZED_E UMINUS_E INT 2)
```

The rule is quite simple: when there is a pair (or triple or more) constructor (e.g. `ADD_E_E`), it prints a new lines for its arguments, each line has another 2 spaces of indentation; when there is a unary constroctor (e.g. `UMINUS_E`), it doesn't print new line.

Almost all the lines have this structure `Printf.fprintf chan  (tercs ... ...) ...`, as they are a lot, I really need to automatize the indentation in a clever way.

One way I think of is to have a ref variable `i` which represents the number of the spaces of the current indentation. We incorporate `i := !i+2` and `i := !i-2` before and after `Printf.fprintf chan (tercs ... ...)`. Also we need to modify the format returned by `tercs`: once there is `\n`, we add `i` spaces after `\n`.

But I have also heard of `box`, `hint`, etc. provided by `Format` module. Does anyone know them well, and is there a more direct solution for my request?

Comment: This was also helpful learning how to use the Format module. http://caml.inria.fr/resources/doc/guides/format.en.html

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an integer parameter  to your functions which will incapsulate how many spaces you should write at the beginning of each line. If you will do some recursive call this value should be increased.

Comment: `String.make offset ' '` will generate the string to print after the line break if the current indentation is `offset`.